# Why did sumo wrestlers ended up having high levels of fat to practice the sport?

Tags: history, sumo-wrestling

Here are some photos from old sumo wrestlers, definitely they are not comparable to current sumo wrestlers in general, having low level of fats.

[image]

[image]

Compared to a sumo wrestler like the following the difference is pretty big:

[image]

Which historical changes made them to change their physiques to practice the sport so much?

Comment: I don't have a hard answer, but it's probably to do with modern abundance of food. I don't know much about the history of Sumo, but I've seen interviews where sumo wrestlers have said eating was part of the job. They don't have weight classes, so they basically want to be as big as they can be without being too big to fight properly.